# Ordering attribute routes - Asp.net core web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In asp.net core web API, attribute routes can configure an order, and these are processed in ascending order. What I can't figure out is a real-life use case where this feature would be handy. Any thought? ([Ordering attribute routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#ordering-attribute-routes))